# keep div on bottom of screen on load, but in original place on scrolldown

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

I'd like to keep a div at the bottom middle of the screen on load, but when the user scrolls down I'd like the div to stay in its original place where it loaded (no at the bottom of the screen) not fixed, but continue scrolling away upwards like the rest of the content.

This html and css will keep it at the bottom middle of the page, but it stays there on scrolldown. I need it it stop coming along lol.

```
    <div id="homeSliderBTN" style="z-index:99;position: fixed;bottom: 0px;left:40%;">
        <img src="images/register.png" >
    </div>
```

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: you'll probably need js, to calculate the height of the viewport on page load and place the div is the correct position from the top, then update that position on resize of the browser

Comment: @ianaya89 I don't know how to achieve this. I just know how to keep it at the bottom, but I was able to make it fade away on scroll down, Although this isn't the intended goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`. Fixed will keep it in place at all time. Absolute will position it where you want but it will scroll with the page:

```
<div id="homeSliderBTN" style="z-index:99;position:absolute;bottom: 0px;left:40%;">
    <img src="images/register.png" >
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmtsfqqh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need `jquery` for that.

You have to `position` your div to `position:fixed;` and with the help of `jquery event scrollTop` you have to change your div value to `position:relative;` it will take that div to actual position.